# SharePoint Java Script Link

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm having problems calling a java script function from within a SharePoint webpart.
I created a java script file to place my functions, and created a reference in the webpart to the .js file with the line:

```
<Sharepoint:ScriptLink ID="scriptlink" runat="server" Name="Webparts_Query.js"></Sharepoint:ScriptLink>
```

--Note this is in the .ascx file.

I have a textbox in the webpart in which on it's 'onblur' event I would like to call a function from the .js file.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onBlur="Items.UpdateListItem();"></asp:TextBox>
```

and here is a simplified version of whats in the .js file.

```
var Items =
{
    UpdateListItem: function()   
    {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
}
```

I think I have everything correct but the function is not being called because I do not see the modal box.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you linking in jQuery.

Comment: Look at the source of your page to make sure the JavaScript file is really called. Also use a `alert("File loaded")` at the end of your JavaScript file, to see if it's correctly loaded. If all OK, you can look at your source code to the TextBox2 to be sure the "onBlur" is set correctly.